# how to copy the contents between same string that are in two different files

Tags: python

I have multiple log files in a folder and i need to copy the log contents of a particular test case which is spread between two files using python.

Find the code here:

```
inFile = open("log2file.txt")
outFile = open("parse2", "w")
copy = False
for line in infile:
    if line.strip() == "Start":
        copy = True
    elif line.strip() == "End":
        copy = False
    elif copy:
        outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: what is the problem here ?

Comment: it works only if both start and end are in same file. I have start and end in different files of same folder

Comment: can you add any example of your data ?